# How to get last value of column in multiple sheets and add them together

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently trying to get the last value of Column "D" in several sheets, then add all the values together, then calculate a percentage based on a value from a main sheet cell.

I can get =VALUE(D:D) to work and =VALUE(Animations!D15), but not a combination of both which is what I need (since the size of the column will continue to grow).

It would be best if it was the last numerical value in column D, and not account for blank spaces or strings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the last populated number in a column use Index with an approximate Match to 1E+99.

```
=index(sheet2!d:d, match(1e99, sheet2!d:d))
```

The above retrieves the last number in column D on Sheet2.

Google sheets will not process an array of worksheet names through INDIRECT like Excel will but a 'helper' column will take care of that. If you want to hard-code a series of worksheet names into a sum of index/match formulas, then Indirect isn't even necessary.

In the accompanying linked worksheet, I've used this method to retrieve the last number from columns with numbers, text and errors. I've thrown in the 'last number' cell address as well.

[image]

[Linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-KT6UlD6xn_uKR2VA4gJEmExD_oxG4z3NLl2qqTH76o/edit?usp=sharing)